# Color transform from ProPhoto RGB to monitor profile

Tags: c++, wcs, color-profile, color-management

I have been struggling many days with this issue and can't find any explanation!

**Background:**

I'm creating a **color managed** photo editing app on Windows with VC9+MFC, and using **WCS**(Windows Color System) APIs to convert pixels from photo embedded color profile to the monitor's profile.

My monitor has been calibrated with the "Windows Display Calibration", and created a profile named "CalibratedDisplayProfile-x.icc".

**Problem:**

When I convert pixels from "ProPhoto RGB" to monitor's profile, the color in the dark area shifts, the tint turns green. This doesn't happen in midtone/highlights if the target profile is sRGB. Here're the screen-shots.

[correct & error images](http://1drv.ms/1drebbs)

**Test:**

To simplify the problem, I wrote some test codes to translate a single color, but the test result really makes me confused. The source color "c0" is **RGB(0,0,65535)**, but the output color "c1" is **RGB(0,0,0)**!! And function "CheckColor" fails with error "Invalid Arguments"...

How could this happen? Am I doing something wrong?

You can download the two profiles here: [Color Profiles](http://1drv.ms/1drecfx)

Thanks very much!

```
CString strProfilePath = _T("C:\\Windows\\System32\\spool\\drivers\\color\\");
CString strSrcProfile  = strProfilePath + _T("ProPhoto.icm");
CString strDstProfile  = strProfilePath + _T("CalibratedDisplayProfile-2.icc");
PROFILE pf = {0};
pf.dwType = PROFILE_FILENAME;
pf.pProfileData = (PVOID)strSrcProfile.GetBuffer();
pf.cbDataSize = (strSrcProfile.GetLength() + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR);
HPROFILE hSrcProfile = ::OpenColorProfile( &pf, PROFILE_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, OPEN_EXISTING );
pf.pProfileData = (PVOID)strDstProfile.GetBuffer();
pf.cbDataSize = (strDstProfile.GetLength() + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR);
HPROFILE hDstProfile = ::OpenColorProfile( &pf, PROFILE_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, OPEN_EXISTING );

HPROFILE hProfiles[2];
hProfiles[0] = hSrcProfile;
hProfiles[1] = hDstProfile;
DWORD dwIndents[2] = { INTENT_RELATIVE_COLORIMETRIC, INTENT_RELATIVE_COLORIMETRIC };
HTRANSFORM hTransform = ::CreateMultiProfileTransform( hProfiles, 2, dwIndents, 2, BEST_MODE, INDEX_DONT_CARE );

COLOR c0, c1;
c0.rgb.red = 0;
c0.rgb.green = 0;
c0.rgb.blue = 0xffff;
::TranslateColors( hTransform, &c0, 1, COLOR_RGB, &c1, COLOR_RGB );

BYTE btResult = 0;
::CheckColors( hTransform, &c0, 1, COLOR_RGB, &btResult );

::DeleteColorTransform( hTransform );
::CloseColorProfile( hSrcProfile );
::CloseColorProfile( hDstProfile );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same issue as yours on Windows 7 SP1 x64.
It seems that [`TranslateColors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd372204(v=vs.85).aspx) function is either broken by design or not supposed to be used that way. I think it's Microsoft's fault as they could write more WCS samples on MSDN.

But I managed to solve the problem using [`TranslateBitmapBits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/dd372203(v=vs.85).aspx) function instead. Here is a sample:

```
bool translateColors(BYTE* srcRgbColors, BYTE* dstRgbColors, DWORD nBytes)
{
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;

    HPROFILE   hSrcProfile       = nullptr;
    HPROFILE   hDstProfile       = nullptr;
    HTRANSFORM hColorTransform   = nullptr;

    /* open source sRGB profile */
    wchar_t* srcProfilePath = L"sRGB Color Space Profile.icm";

    tagPROFILE targetProfile;
    targetProfile.dwType = PROFILE_FILENAME;
    targetProfile.pProfileData = srcProfilePath;
    targetProfile.cbDataSize = sizeof(wchar_t) * (wcslen(srcProfilePath) + 1);

    hSrcProfile = OpenColorProfile(&targetProfile, PROFILE_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, OPEN_EXISTING);
    if (nullptr == hSrcProfile) goto EXIT;

    /* open destination monitor profile */
    wchar_t* dstProfilePath = L"ActiveMonitorProfile.icm";

    tagPROFILE destinationProfile;
    destinationProfile.dwType = PROFILE_FILENAME;
    destinationProfile.pProfileData = dstProfilePath;
    destinationProfile.cbDataSize = sizeof(wchar_t) * (wcslen(dstProfilePath) + 1);

    hDstProfile = OpenColorProfile(&destinationProfile, PROFILE_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, OPEN_EXISTING);
    if (nullptr == hDstProfile) goto EXIT;

    /* create color transform */

    DWORD dwIntent = (DWORD)-1;
    HPROFILE hProfileList[2] = { hSrcProfile, hDstProfile };

    hColorTransform = CreateMultiProfileTransform(
        hProfileList,
        2,
        &dwIntent,
        1,
        NORMAL_MODE,
        INDEX_DONT_CARE
    );

    if (nullptr == hColorTransform) goto EXIT;

    /* transform colors */
    DWORD dwWidth = nBytes / 3; // 3 channels per pixel, 8 bits per channel, RGB format

    bResult = TranslateBitmapBits(
        hColorTransform,
        srcRgbColors,
        BM_RGBTRIPLETS,
        dwWidth,        // bitmap width
        1,              // bitmap height
        0,
        dstRgbColors,
        BM_RGBTRIPLETS,
        0,
        nullptr,
        0
    );

EXIT:
    /* free resources */
    if (nullptr != hColorTransform) {
        DeleteColorTransform(hColorTransform);
    }

    if (nullptr != hSrcProfile) {
        CloseColorProfile(hSrcProfile);
    }

    if (nullptr != hDstProfile) {
        CloseColorProfile(hDstProfile);
    }

    return bResult == FALSE ? false : true;
}

/* example usage */
BYTE srcBitmapData[3];
srcBitmapData[0] = 0x1c;
srcBitmapData[1] = 0x1a;
srcBitmapData[2] = 0x1a;

BYTE dstOutputBitmapData[3];
bool bResult = traslateColors(srcBitmapData, dstOutputBitmapData, 3);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using LittleCMS now. It's much better.